# jquery 1.9.1 disable radionbuttonlist listitem

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

I'm using asp.net.  I'd like to disable a specific item in a asp:radiobuttonlist. I'm also using jquery 1.9.1 and have read that instead of the attr I should be using prop.  I can't get either to work at this point.. was hoping someone could help.  Here is the radiobuttonlist

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblRegister" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Original Entry" Value="OE" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Promotional" Value="P" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I've tried several different ways of doing this.. none of them are working.  As you can see, i'm trying to get the Origninal Entry list item to be disabled

```
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblRegister_0 option[value='OE']").prop("disabled", true);
        $("[id$=rblRegister option[value='OE']]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("[id$=rblRegister option[value='OE']]").prop("disabled", true);
```

any help would be great.
thanks
Shannon

Here is what the rendered html looks like

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblRegister_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblRegister" value="OE">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the `prop()` syntax because it is expecting an object.

```
$('input').prop({'disabled':true})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLjPe/)

Comment: thanks for the code.. that disables the entire drop down list.. that is good code to have.  what about disabling a single list item.  I tried $('input option[value='high']').prop({'disabled': true}); from your fiddle example(thanks for that by the way) and my syntax must not be correct

Comment: I am not familiar with ASP, could you post the raw HTML that ASP produces?

Comment: Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLjPe/4/) for a better idea of how to narrow down your selection.